# Excluding a Range in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, range

I have a valid range and I'm trying to find documents that are outside of this range.
The range query in elastic will return values within a certain range. I've tried putting the range query in a `must_not`, but that doesn't seem to be working for me or I'm using it incorrectly.

I'm prototyping at the moment, so I've set up an index with two records in it, for example:

```
{
    "name": "Alex",
    "value": 30.0
}

{
    "name": "James",
    "value": 36.5
}
```

my `must_not` block looks like this (note its in a `bool` because I'm checking some other fields in a `must match_phrase` which works fine):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
            "lt": 31,
            "gt" : 36.6,
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'd expect it to return nothing because 30 (Alex) is not less than 29 !(30 < 29) and 36.5 (James) is not less than !(36.5 > 36.6) but returns all records

I'm new to Elastic so I might be looking at this the completely wrong way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried having two elements in the must_not array? One for lt, one for gt?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a single range query for disjoint intervals, you need to have two, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "lt": 31
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gt": 36.6
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this query will still return James result. but he is expecting no result.

Comment: My point was just that the OP cannot have a single range query for two disjoint intervals. Results or no results simply depend on the bounds that the OP uses

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
POST i1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "lt": 31,
              "gt": 36.6
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "k1": "something"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your query must_not  （<31 and >36.6） while return all data